# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'owner' when trying to access relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to load a value on the `Toy.owner` relationshiop.  These are my models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50))
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on":type,
        'polymorphic_identity':'user',
        'with_polymorphic':'*'
    }

class Owner(User):
    __tablename__ = 'Owner'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, unique=True)  
    toys = db.relationship('Toy', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'owner'}

class Toy(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Toy'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Owner.owner_id'))
```

This view should use `clicked_toy.owner_id`:

```
@app.route('/<path:toy_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def toy_info(toy_id):
    clicked_toy = db.session.query(Toy).filter(Toy.id == toy_id).first()
    owner = db.session.query(Owner).filter(Owner.owner_id == clicked_toy.owner.owner_id).first()
    return render_template('toy_info.html', clicked_toy=clicked_toy, owner=owner)
```

This does not work, I got the error:

```
File ".../controller.py", line 67, in toy_info
owner = db.session.query(Owner).filter(Owner.owner_id == clicked_toy.owner.owner_id).first()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'owner'
```

When I tried to call `clicked_toy.owner_id` instead, I got same error:

```
 File ".../controller.py", line 67, in toy_info
 owner = db.session.query(Owner).filter(Owner.owner_id == clicked_toy.owner_id).first()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'owner_id'
```

What am I missing and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.first()` returns `None` if there were no results.  So your query for `clicked_toy` returned no results.

You can use `get` rather than `filter` when all you're doing is filtering on the primary key.  Flask-SQLAlchemy goes one step further by allowing you to raise 404 if there is no result.

```
clicked_toy = Toy.query.get_or_404(toy_id)
```